# Index/Dashboard/Homepage Best Practice and Customs

Tags: python, html, django

I'm currently developing a project to store all of my old MP3 files. This project contains multiple applications(Artist, Album, Song) and I'm simply curious to know if it is common for developers to create a separate application which may be named something like 'Dashboard' and use this to host their homepage, login/logout functionality, search features, recently uploaded items, etc. Or is it more common to just stick your homepage into an existing app?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call an approach best practice, however certain practices are commonly used-

- `core` app is created where it's a small project (i.e. probably three or less models and around five views). Dashboard can be a template in this app. You're correct, usually it's common to stick your homepage into an existing app.
- `account` app is created to keep the authentication system separate.

Other approaches are also good.